# Fork/Join kill siblings/branches

Tags: java

I'm using Fork/Join to recursively search for a solution to a problem.

```
      /——----1------\
  /--1.1--\     /--1.2--\
1.1.1   1.1.2 1.2.1   1.2.2
```

Now lets say I find the solution in 1.2.1. Is there a way to cancel all other process in the forkjoin pool?

Whatabout if I know that 1.1 and 1.2 each contain a potential solution - so I only want to cancel my siblings (and any sub forks they may have spawned)?

I could used some shared object flag, but I hoped Fork/Join had a cleaner way to kill off branches or siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once started it goes to completion or Error/Exception.

You would have to program a cancel yourself. That is, pass a volatile boolean to each Task, when ready set the boolean to true (cancel). Each Task can test the boolean for true and just stop immediately.