# Abort a RecursiveTask with a given result?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap, fork-join

I'm facing the following problem:

I do interate over a ConcurrentHashMap with the help of a RecursiveAction for dividing and conquering the map.

The problem is that I need to return the first result found for a specific criteria or if nothing is found I need to return null when all "split-tasks" are done.

For now (due to the fact that I'm using RecursiveAction instead of RecursiveTask) I'm just able to call a method and do "return;" when a task found a match but thats smells very bad.

All solutions I tried with implementing a RecursiveTask needed to go through the whole map (doing all splits) until I could return a value.

Is there any possibility to return a given result and cancel the task to prevend furthing processing using a RecursiveTask?

Comment: It should be simple - just don't create any sub-tasks?

Comment: how do you mean that? no fork/join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this old [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674546/fork-join-kill-siblings-branches/22695404#22695404) will help. It's a form of "short circuit" and you need to do it all yourself. Or you can use a package from another.